# Initialize the many objects from a dictionary Python?

Tags: python, class

I have a class that takes a large dict and initialize constructors to set the class members. However, when I run pylint, I keep getting the Too many public methods message. My question is what is there a good practice or is there a better pythonic way to initialize the many objects?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, tmp_dict):
        self.val1 = tmp_dict.get('val1')
        self.val2 = tmp_dict.get('val2')
        self.val3 = tmp_dict.get('val3')
        .
        .
        .
        self.val100 = tmp_dict.get('val100')



tmp_dict = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 1 , ..., "val100":1}

MyClass(tmp_dict)
```

Comment: Why not just use the dictionary itself? `self.vals = tmp_dict`

Answer (score -1):

As Woodford mentioned, you could just use the dictionary itself by doing `self.vals = tmp_dict` and then accessing the values like `obj.vals['val1']`

However to achieve the result you asked for, you could defining the class like this (edited to fix the valid issue presented by wim):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, tmp_dict):
        self.__dict__.update(tmp_dict)
```

You could then access the attributes like this, although the first method of just using the dictionary directly is probably safer and more pythonic:

```
this_dict = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 1}

obj = MyClass(this_dict)
print(obj.val1)
```

Comment: Wholesale replacing `self.__dict__` with a new namespace is a bad idea. It might already have some stuff in it, e.g. names from a derived class.